# subversion: how to view comments placed on tags

Tags: svn, tags

How can I view the comments on the tags in svn? Assume I create a tag:

```
svn cp -m"vhost apache config" file:///var/svn/repos/foo/trunk file:///var/svn/repos/foo/tags/release-0.1
```

Later, I have tagged many times, and I need to find out what each tag is about. I can use:

```
svn ls --verbose file:///var/svn/repos/foo/tags
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r50 | user | 2010-03-03 18:11:50 -0500 (Wed, 03 Mar 2010) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   A /foo/tags/release-0.1/trunk (from /foo/trunk:49)

vhost apache config
```

The information is there, but with a large list of tags it's difficult to pick out the log entry that will tell me which tag I'm interested in. In this case it's "vhost apache config". Is it possible to simply list all tags, and the comment that was applied at creation (copy) time?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are working correctly and do not commit any other changes into your tag-folder exept creation of tags, the answer is simple:

```
svn log file:///var/svn/repos/foo/tags
```

You get some output like this:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r12 | pparker | 2010-02-22 13:13:24 +0100 (Mo, 22. Feb 2010) | 1 Row

creating tag after locking exercise
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r1 | pparker | 2010-02-22 13:13:17 +0100 (Mo, 22. Feb 2010) | 1 Row

initial repository structure
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Explanation:
You will get all changes happend to the tags directory. These changes are usually just the creation of new tags. So you will get for each tag  1 log entry.
If you are interested in the appropriate tags, just add the *-v* option

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use a tool like `grep` or TortoiseSVN's regex filter to filter the output of `svn log` so that only entries that signify the addition of a directory under `/tags/` are displayed.